# Missing last element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, primes

I'm trying to sum all primes up to a number.

First I removed all evens and pushed the rest to an odd-only array.

Then I'm going over the array and splicing all the numbers that divide by other numbers but 1 and themselves, and replacing them with zero.

Everything seemed to go okay, however, notice in my first console.log that the last element is 977 (which is the num passed).

A line later I forEach the array and print all numbers over 970 but 977 isn't there.

Any ideas on how this happened? (I ruled out voodoo..)

```js
function sumPrimes(num) {
  
  var arr = [2];
  for (var i = 3; i <= num; i++) {
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
  }

  console.log(arr);
  arr.forEach(function(x) {
    
    if(x > 970){
      console.log(x);
    }
    
    if (x > 3) {
      for (var j = 3; j < x; j += 2) {
        if (x % j == 0) {
          arr.splice(arr.indexOf(x), 1, 0);
        }
      }
    }
  })

  // console.log(arr);
  var res = arr.reduce(function(acc, val) {
    return acc + val;
  }, 0)
  console.log(res);
}

sumPrimes(977);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is how you're manipulating the array and the array never actually ends up containing 977.

What happens is you find a non-prime and alter the array in place so that it's now 0 but you continue to run checks on that prime.

This causes any following indexOf lookup for that value to return -1 and hence you get unexpected results.

```
if (x % j == 0) {
   arr.splice(arr.indexOf(x), 1, 0); // This won't work after the first assign to 0
}
```

You can easily fix this by inserting a 'break;' immediately following the splice to short circuit the loop, however you can easily simplify & dramatically speed this up using the index parameter available in a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to remove the array position lookup entirely.

```js
function sumPrimes(num) {

  var arr = [2];
  for (var i = 3; i <= num; i++) {
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
  }

  console.log(arr);
  arr.forEach(function(x, idx) {

    if(x > 970){
      console.log(x);
    }

    if (x > 3) {
      for (var j = 3; j < x; j += 2) {
        if (x % j == 0) {
          arr[idx] = 0;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  })

  // console.log(arr);
  var res = arr.reduce(function(acc, val) {
    return acc + val;
  }, 0)
  console.log(res);
}

sumPrimes(977);
```

---

EDIT: If anyone wants a simple, more efficient method of determining whether a number is prime or not, I suggest using the [Trial Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) method, not the one above.

You can find a succinct, well tested example on [Rosetta code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Primality_by_trial_division#JavaScript):

```js
function isPrime(n) {
  if (n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 5 || n == 7) {
    return true;
  } else if ((n < 2) || (n % 2 == 0)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    for (var i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 2) {
      if (n % i == 0)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}

console.log(isPrime(977));
```

Comment: I did some tests on these algorithms a few years ago and eliminating multiples of numbers up to /13 (if I remember correct) was returning gains on huge inputs. After that, it just wasn't worth it. Wouldn't this later function be about twice as fast if you implemented a helper function to build an array first? 
function buildArray(n) {
  var arr = [2, 3, 5, 7];

  for (i = 13; i < n; i+=2) {
    if(isPrime(i)) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
  }
  return arr;
} -----and also elimanted your first two conditionals

Comment: It could be made somewhat faster, however I didn't want to deviate too far from his original code. Personally I would have solved it using a prime sieve.

Comment: Have you implemented Miller-Rabin before? It's worth doing if you have time and are interested. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test

Comment: @DaveL Thanks a lot, i've actually did the Trial Division in a previous try but also missed the break part, while trying everything from scratch i stumbled upon this thing and couldn't stop until I understood the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Dave's answer is correct, but for the sake of this exercise, another loop solution

```
        function sumPrimes(num) {

            var prime = [2];
            var isPrime;

            for (var i = 3; i <= num; i++) {

                if (i % 2 !== 0) {
                    isPrime = true;

                    prime.forEach(function (v) {
                        isPrime = isPrime && i % v != 0;
                    });

                    if (isPrime) {
                        prime.push(i);
                    }
                }
            }

            console.log(prime);
            var res = prime.reduce(function (acc, val) {
                return acc + val;
            }, 0)
            console.log(res);
        }

        sumPrimes(977);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Dave L also spotted, the issue seems to be with this:

```
if (x > 3) {
      for (var j = 3; j < x; j += 2) {
        if (x % j == 0) {
          arr.splice(arr.indexOf(x), 1, 0);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

When I commented it out, 977 was printed out, but with it in place, I had to try with 979 to have it print 977. The reason you probably never suspected it is because JavaScript is asyncrhonous, so this actually got exectued *before* the log statement!

Comment: In this case it's not actually async breaking the log, it's how he's altering the array. See my (now expanded) answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using array.reduce, why don't you also use array.map to seed your array with initial values (instead of using a for loop)?

```
function seedArray(start, end) {
  return Array.apply(null, new Array(end - start + 1)).map(
    function(x, i) {
      return i + start;
    }
  );
}
```

Of course you can do some error checking to make sure p1 and p2 are non-negative integers and p2 >= p1 to make sure new Array() will not crash.